# Don't have the page refresh after selectedindexchanged of dropdown list?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working with two dropdown boxes after a user selects the first required drop down based on what they choose the other drop down will load the final list. I have that working but I don't want the page to reload on once the first dropdown option is picked is there a way around this below is my test code

```js
Behind code

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("3 Days", "3 Days"));
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("4 Days", "4 Days"));
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("5 Days", "5 Days"));
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("7 Days", "7 Days"));
            }
        }

        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList2.Items.Clear();
            DropDownList3.Items.AddRange(GetListItems(DropDownList1.SelectedValue));
        }

        private ListItem[] GetListItems(string value)
        {
            var items = new List
                <ListItem>
                ();

            if (value == "3 Days")
            {
                DropDownList2.Items.Add(new ListItem("1", "1"));
            }

            if (value == "4 Days")
            {
                DropDownList2.Items.Add(new ListItem("2", "2"));
            }

            if (value == "5 Days")
            {
                DropDownList2.Items.Add(new ListItem("3", "3"));
            }

            if (value == "7 Days")
            {
                DropDownList2.Items.Add(new ListItem("4", "4"));
            }
            return items.ToArray();
        }
```

```html
<div class="1">
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
  <asp:ListItem Text="Select..." Value="No selection made"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</div>
<div class="1">
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select..." Value="No selection made"></asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Comment: The only way to do it without a page reload is to use AJAX rather than posting.  Are you open to using JQuery?

Comment: I'm very new to this can you explain in more detail?

Comment: Wrap your `DropDownList` inside a Update Panel, only section under DropDown List would reload asynchronously rest of page won't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

([FROM MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx))
The ScriptManager control and the UpdatePanel control. These controls remove the requirement to refresh the whole page with each postback, which improves the user experience. By default, a postback control (such as a button) inside an UpdatePanel control causes a partial-page update. By default, a button or other control outside an UpdatePanel control causes the whole page to be refreshed,

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <fieldset>
            <div class="1">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Select..." Value="No selection made"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
            <div class="1">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Select..." Value="No selection made"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use [JQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp) with an [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call in order to avoid postback.

First, you'll need to remove the auto postback and event handler from your drop down list:

```
<div class="1">
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem Text="Select..." Value="No selection made"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</div>
<div class="1">
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select..." Value="No selection made"></asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Then, use JQuery to make a call which sends the selected option and returns the options for the second drop down list.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#<%=DropDownList1.ClientID%>').change(function() {
            var selectedOption = $(this).val();
            console.log(selectedOption); //verify you have the value
            $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "codebehind.aspx/GetListItems",
                  data: JSON.stringify({ value: selectionOption }),
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  dataType: "json"
                }).success(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);  //verify the format of the return data
                    obj = JSON.parse(data.d);
                    console.log(obj); //verify obj structure
                    //adding options to drop down list will look something like...
                    $.each(data, function (index, optiondata) {
                        $("#DropDownList2").append("<option value='" + optiondata.Value + "'>" + optiondata.Text + "</option>");
                    });

                });
    });
});
</script>
```

And you'll need to change your function in code behind to:

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<ListItem> GetListItems(string value)
{

   //..do stuff

   return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
}
```

Comment: as soon as I remove the Autopost and event handler the second dropdown no longer loads the options. Secondly using the code behind now i'm getting errors that C# this member can not be referenced from a static-context

Comment: The Dropdown list should be empty until you have the AJAX stuff working.  My answer has a couple of references linked for AJAX and JQuery, but those are by no means exhaustive.  You may need to get up to speed on how to link in JQuery (including document.ready and script tags).  I'll update my answer with a couple of extra helpers to point you in the right way.  Also, the whole point is to populate the drop down list without postback so your page doesn't refresh.  You will need to address the static references errors, as the AJAX / Webmethod requires your GetListItems to be a static function.

Answer (score 1):

The act of including `ClientIDMode="Static"` to the DDL was the culprit in my case. I know this isn't the case with OP's markup, but a subset of users reading this will be in the same boat I was. Just passing it along.